# SQL - Accessing only the first row of a struct value in a specific column

Tags: sql, arrays, string, struct, google-bigquery

here is the format of my table.

> custom_fields RECORD  REPEATED
> custom_fields. value    RECORD  NULLABLE
> custom_fields.value. name   STRING  NULLABLE
> custom_fields.value. value  STRING  NULLABLE

I want to access to "custom_fields.value.name".
I tried:

```
SELECT * from [my_database] 
WHERE custom_fields.value.name = "something";
```

> Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<value STRUCT<name STRING, value STRING>>> at [1:78]

I may work with another table because I feel that the format is really tough to work easily with. But I will appreciate your ideas on this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are available in very few databases.  But in those that do, you would need to *index* the array.  The error message looks like BigQuery.

If you want to look at the *first* value, then you would use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [my_database] 
WHERE custom_fields[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)].value.name = 'something';
```

If you wanted to return rows where *any value* matches, then use `UNNEST()` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [my_database] 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(custom_fields) cf WHERE cf.value.name = 'something');
```

If you wanted only the elements from `customer_fields` that match, then move the `UNNEST()` to the FROM`:

```
SELECT t.* EXCEPT (customer_fields), cf 
FROM [my_database] t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(custom_fields) cf
WHERE cf.value.name = 'something');
```

Comment: Super ! Indeed it works pretty well. Yes i'm using BigQuery (not used too but I have to ...). Thank you very much for your help @a_horse_with_no_name